# Put quote into a value attribute html

Tags: html, html-escape-characters

Given a form input field for example `<input type="text" value="xxxxx" name="something">`
Given a string let's say `Hello I said "Your my friend" isn't that nice?`

How do I safely enter the given string as the value where 'xxxxx' is in the input tag above?

Doing a straight substitution would cause this:
`<input type="text" value="Hello I said "Your my friend" isn't that nice?">`
As you can see the end result is not coherent. The value is now `Hello I said` there is a bunch of improper text, than another string, not good.

How do you safely enter strings of unknown or potentially unsafe characters into these kinds of HTML attributes?

Comment: There are several existing questions on the topic. Moreover, the issue can almost always be avoided by using proper punctuation, as per rules of human languages, e.g. `"Hello I said “Your my friend” isn’t that nice?"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

```
<input type="text" value="Hello I said &quot;Your my friend&quot; isn't that nice?">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple solutions and you can choose the one you like:

Hack:
1. You can simply use the ' character for the outer quotes and safely use the " character for the text inside. `<input type="text" value='this "should work"' name="something">`

Proper way:
2. Encode the character according to HTML character references [HERE](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ent4_frame.html)

"`<input type="text" value="this &quot;should work&quot;" name="something">` or `<input type="text" value="this &#34;should work&#34;" name="something">`